What is this vegetable?

I don’t know this food. Can you help identify it?

Hi Dini, we only do "how do I use it" for things that are very rarely used as food. For anything else, it's better to use a recipe database than asking our users to make random suggestions. So I reduced your question to the part "what is it", which is within our scope.

And to all our other users: please don't add answers (or partial answers) in comments. Even if it feels like it's "too easy" to be a real answer - sometimes there are easy questions and that's OK.

Its good deep fried, or you can split it along the side and microwave it. It tends to be gooey undercooked

That looks like okra pods (also called ladyfingers) to me. Check the inside, to be sure.

Not to be confused with the type of ladyfingers used in desserts.

I agree that it's almost certainly okra.  But check the inside for what, please?

Check the inside if it looks like okra (compare it to the picture in the linked wikipedia article). To rule out the small chance, that it might be something else but okra.

This is okra, you can use it to cook gumbo or make fried okra.

This doesn't seem to add anything useful to the already existing, accepted answer.

It's lady's fingers, or just ocra/okra. Here you find more about this plant. Don't boil it too long, because it loses all the nutrients.

I've never seen the spelling "ocra" - to me that's an acronym for "Optical Character Recognition Algorithm", but maybe that's just domain-specific.
